# Why is returned object an rvalue?

Tags: c++, lvalue, rvalue

```
class A {}

A foo() {
  A a;
  // some work
  return a;
}
```

Here it returns an instance of `A`, and I saw many readings saying that this returns a `rvalue`.

My confusion is, since it's perfectly legit to do `A b; a = b;`, the variable `a` seems to be an `lvalue`. So why does it become `rvalue` when it's the returned one?

Comment: Can you do `foo() = foo();`?

Comment: See my updates. This may make it clearer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, technically speaking, yes [you can](http://ideone.com/sbLFTq).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as an rvalue *object*.

Rvalue and lvalue refers to *expressions*.

One expression that refers to an object can be an rvalue, while another that refers to the same object can be an lvalue.

---

Originally "lvalue" referred to any expression that could be on the left hand side of C's `=`, while "rvalue" was any expression that could only be on the right side. Since then C++ has acquired `const` and references, and things have got complicated. But the early C view of things is useful to understand this.

---

Regarding …

> **”** the variable `a` seems to be an lvalue. So why does it become rvalue when it's the returned one?

Well, the variable in itself is not an lvalue. The expression `a` is an lvalue. And the function does not return the variable: it returns the variable's *value*.

So, as I understand it there are two misconceptions involved in the question:

- The idea that lvalue/rvalue is about objects. It's about expressions.
- The idea that `A foo() { return... }` return a reference to an object (as in e.g. Java). It returns a value.

Comment: The return value could be a temporary object though. There is clearly an object in the case `foo().bar();`

Answer (score 0):

An `lvalue` is an expression that refers to a memory location and allows us to take the address of that memory location via the & operator. An `rvalue` is an expression that is not an `lvalue`.

See here http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html

In your example, you're returning a copy of a stack allocated instance. But that is likely also on the stack and is a 'temporary copy', hence you cannot take the address of it. Hence it's not an `lvalue`, therefore it's an `rvalue`

Comment: What if we do `&(foo())`? We are taking the addr of the returned `a`, right?

Comment: "and allows us to take the address of that memory location via the `&` operator", that is not always the case, if as strongly indicated you mean direct application of `&`. It is however, AFAIK, always possible to cast to reference to char and then take the address.

Comment: @OneZero Taking the address of a tempory isn't valid C++.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, you can try taking the address of the value of a return-by-copy function and see what that gets you.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz: you failed to understand what I wrote, by failing to understand the context (possibly being just to quick on the trigger finger, in which case you know how to improve). just to clarify, your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @OneZero, no, that won't work. It's a temporary object and the memory will be destroyed once the function completes. So you'd be referencing deleted memory. As juanchopanza says, it's not valid C++.  You can say `A b; A* a = &(b = foo());`  Just understand that what is happening is that the copy-ctor of A is being called at the return of `foo()` Then another copy-ctor is being applied on the assignment `b = foo();` then you're taking the address of `b` and assigning it to `a`;

Comment: @juanchopanza: re "Taking the address of a tempory isn't valid C++.", ITYM "applying the built-in `&` directly to a temporary isn't valid C++".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, ok, maybe so. Just show me where you can *"cast to reference to char and then take the address"* of a stack allocated temporary object and have it survive as a valid pointer to memory that won't be overwritten by something else.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz imagine an object with a member function that returns reference to `*this` (or pointer `this`). I think Alf is pointing out that you can actually end up with such a pointer/reference, even though it will be dangling as soon as the full-expression ends. (The temporary objects all survive until the end of the full-expression, so you could do some things with this pointer/reference).

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz: You're still jumping to silly conclusions, and now two of them are wrong. (1) I didn't write about rvalues. (2) But, one can very simply take the address of a temporary, in a roundabout way, and have it survive to the end of the full-expression, and that's often very useful. I think it's nice that you *ask* though.

Comment: @M.M, Guess what that's an `lvalue` not an rvalue. You'll note that those function's return signature is `MyObject& foo1() { return *this; }` An entirely different beast than `MyObject foo2() { return *this; }` The first returns a reference, an `lvalue`, the second returns a temporary copy an `rvalue`.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz no that isn't how it works. (See Alf's answer). A common example might be `std::string x() { return "foo"; }  int main() { std::cout << x().c_str(); }`. This is correct even though `x()` is an rvalue.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, Well, it's for sure we don't seem to be communicating. But, I think what you and M.M are suggesting is dangerous code. It may be true that it *'survives to the end of the expression'*, but suppose someone comes along and changes that expression. Then boom.

Comment: @M.M, that doesn't mean you can take the address of the return of `std::string x() { return "foo"; }`!!! (Except temporarily during the "expression") That's the whole point.

Comment: If code is dangerous if it breaks when someone changes it, then all code is dangerous and describing some code as dangerous doesn't tell us anything about it.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Yes you can take the address . If your point is that this address can't be used after the expression ends, then we all agree. However you didn't say that originally, and Alf was pointing out that the address *can* be used during the rest of the expression, and actually this is useful in many cases.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, point taken. Not gonna argue here anymore. You're all welcome to continue on.

Comment: @M.M, that **is** my point. and always was. And a fair reading of my post will see that. And further, I'm not sure that such code will compile (using the built-in `&` operator). Anyway, I'm done.